# while writing into error: csv unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'float' and 'str'

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I am new to python. I have to write data into `csv file` but it is giving error

> unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'float' and 'str'

```
with open('Csvc1s.csv', "wb") as file:         
    file.write("Time, Total_network\'s_Belief, Total_network\'s_Disbelief, Total_network\'s_Uncertainty")
    file.write('\n')
    list1 = [float(i) for i in timeVar]
    list2 = [float(i) for i in beliefVar]
    list3 = [float(i) for i in disbelVar]
    list4 = [float(i) for i in uncerVar]

    for x in range(0,list1Len):
         textToWrite = (list1[x]) +  "," + (list2[x]) + "," + (list3[x]) + "," + (list4[x])
         file.write(textToWrite.rstrip())
         file.write('\n')
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Do you understand the error message?

Comment: while writing data into csv i cannot write float as str

Comment: @Samradnyee. That's not what it says. It says you can't *add* a float to a str.

Comment: okay. Got it . but how could I write `list1, list2, list3, list4` data into different columns in csv. I aslo tried with `textToWrite = '{},{},{},{}\n'.format(list1[x], list2[x], list3[x], list4[x])`

Comment: `file.write(str(list1[x]) + " " + str(list2[x]) + " " + str(list3[x]) + " " + str(list4[x]) + "\n")`     this worked perfectly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are trying to create a CSV file, the usual approach is to use Python's CSV library. This correctly handles converting lists of data into correctly delimited rows in a file:

```
import csv

with open('Csvc1s.csv', 'w', newline='') as f_output:         
    csv_output = csv.writer(f_output)
    csv_output.writerow(["Time", "Total_network's_Belief", "Total_network's_Disbelief", "Total_network's_Uncertainty"])
    csv_output.writerows(zip(timeVar, beliefVar, disbelVar, uncerVar))
```

`zip()` is used to combine multiple lists together such that each time it is iterated on, the next element from each list is returned as a list (i.e. in this case a whole row). `writerows()` takes a list of rows and automatically adds the necessary `,` between each entry and a `\n` for each row when writing to the file.

Note, this assumes that your four lists of data all have the same length.

Comment: done with it.. Thank you.. `zip` function is working